# Incorporate JSON into YAML with Indentation

Tags: json, ruby, yaml, chef-infra

I'm trying to incorporate a JSON into a YAML file.
The YAML looks like this:
filebeat.inputs:

```
- type: log  
  <incorporate here with a single level indent>
  enabled: true  
  paths:
```

Suppose you have the following variable:

```
a = { processors: { drop_event: { when: { or: [ {equals: { status: 500 }},{equals: { status: -1 }}]}}}}
```

I want to incorporate it into an existing YAML.
I've tried to use:

```
JSON.parse((a).to_json).to_yaml
```

After applying this, I got a valid YAML but without indentation (all lines have to be indented) and with a "---" which is Ruby's new document in YAML.
The result:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
---
processors:
  drop_event:
    when:
      or:
      - equals:
          status: 500
      - equals:
          status: -1
  enabled: true
```

The result I'm looking for:

````
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  processors:
    drop_event:
      when:
        or:
        - equals:
            status: 500
        - equals:
            status: -1
  enabled: true```
````

Answer (score 2):

It’s easier to produce a valid ruby object by merging hashes and *then* serialize the result to YAML than vice versa.

```
puts(yaml.map do |hash|
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), acc|
    # the trick: we insert before "enabled" key
    acc.merge!(JSON.parse(a.to_json)) if k == "enabled"
    # regular assignment for all hash elements
    acc[k] = v
  end
end.to_yaml)
```

Results in:

```
---
- type: log
  processors:
    drop_event:
      when:
        or:
        - equals:
            status: 500
        - equals:
            status: -1
  enabled: true
```

---

`JSON.parse(a.to_json)` basically converts symbols to strings.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do that first you need to convert your original YAML into JSON

```
original = YAML.load(File.read(File.join('...', 'filebeat.inputs')))
# => [
       {
         "type": "log", 
         "enabled": true, 
         "paths": null
       }
     ]
```

Then you have to merge your `JSON` into this `original` variable

```
original[0].merge!(a.stringify_keys)
original.to_yaml
# => 
---
-
  type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
  processors:
    drop_event:
      when:
        or:
        - equals:
            status: 500
        - equals:
            status: -1
```

Comment: This won’t preserve the order of the resulting hash. Also, this screws up the keys in `yaml` by converting them to symbols.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin there is no warranty in order of Ruby hashes, and actually, it does not make any sense, JSON and YAML both are key-value file formats which do not take care about the order at all

Comment: is there any purposes to keep this order?

Comment: Plain wrong. There **indeed is** a warranty in the order of ruby hashes since v2.0 (maybe even v1.9,) and you cannot make the decision for OP. Maybe it’s parsed with 3rd party library that cares about the order.

Comment: There is a purpose of answering questions that were actually asked.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks for the clarification, I just noted that it should be on the first level of indentation. Anyway, it strange for me to keep a strict order as it becomes more fragile. In your answer, the solution has hardcoded string so it will result in failure if we decide to remove or rename `enabled` key. So would pick a very strong reason to stick with exact order and avoid it in any key-value file formats at all.

Comment: We basically have a Filebeat configuration file in YAML. It's more about indentation than order. Keeping the order is just easier for us to look at. The YAML file is already in our repository and is injected by Chef during provisioning.